WPFのPopupからNullReferenceExceptionが発生する問題の回避を、Popup内で解決したい
実現したいこと
UIのデザインは変えずに、Popup要素か、Popup内の要素を修正することでエラーを回避したいです。
Popupの裏に隠れた要素に対して修正を行う方法だと、Popupの位置やサイズを変更したら別の要素で再発する可能性があります。
再現手順

"Open"にマウスカーソルを合わせます。
横並びの3つのボタンが表示されるので、"Left"のボタンにマウスカーソルを合わせます。
ツールチップが表示されたら、"Left"のボタンをクリックします。

NullReferenceExceptionが発生して、プログラムが終了します。

スタックトレース
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=PresentationFramework
  スタック トレース:
   場所 System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.<HideWindow>b__130_0(Object sender, EventArgs args) (System.Windows.Controls.Primitives\Popup.cs):行 1934
   場所 System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.FireTick()
   場所 System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   場所 System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   場所 System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   場所 MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   場所 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- 直前の場所からのスタック トレースの終わり ---
   場所 System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   場所 MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   場所 System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   場所 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   場所 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   場所 MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   場所 MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   場所 System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   場所 System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   場所 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   場所 MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   場所 MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   場所 System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   場所 System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore) (System.Windows\Application.cs):行 1787
   場所 System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window) (System.Windows\Application.cs):行 1459
   場所 WpfSandbox.App.Main()

判明しているエラーの回避方法
x:Name="LabelBorder"の要素に以下のようなスタイルを追加することで回避できることがわかっています。
<Border.Style>
  <Style TargetType="Border">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ThreeButtonPopup, Path=IsOpen}" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
      </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
</Border.Style> 

その他
ToolTipを未設定にしたり、Popup.AllowsTransparencyをfalseにすることでもエラーは発生しなくなるのですが、UIのデザインが変わるので諦めました。
環境

Visual Studio 2022
.NET 7
Windows 11

XAML
<Window
  x:Class="WpfSandbox.MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="200">
  <Grid Height="40" Width="80">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border x:Name="LabelBorder" Grid.Column="0" Background="Orange" ToolTip="Label">          
      <TextBlock Text="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
    <Border x:Name="OpenButton" Grid.Column="1" Background="Aqua">
      <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ThreeButtonPopup, Path=IsOpen}" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
            </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
      </Border.Style>
      <Border.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard TargetName="ThreeButtonPopup" TargetProperty="IsOpen">
              <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00" Value="True"/>
              </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Border.Triggers>
      <TextBlock Text="Open" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Border>
    <Popup x:Name="ThreeButtonPopup" AllowsTransparency="True" StaysOpen="False" PopupAnimation="Fade" Placement="Center" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=OpenButton}">
      <Border Margin="10">
        <Border.Triggers>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseLeave">
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="ThreeButtonPopup" TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                  <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
          <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
              <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="ThreeButtonPopup" TargetProperty="IsOpen" >
                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames FillBehavior="HoldEnd">
                  <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="False"/>
                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
              </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
          </EventTrigger>
        </Border.Triggers>
        <Border.Effect>
          <DropShadowEffect Direction="0" BlurRadius="10"/>
        </Border.Effect>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Button Height="40" Width="40" ToolTip="Left" Content="Left"/>
          <Button Height="40" Width="40" ToolTip="Center" Content="Center"/>
          <Button Height="40" Width="40" ToolTip="Right" Content="Right"/>
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
    </Popup>
  </Grid>
</Window>



環境
Visual Studio 2022
.NET 7
Windows 11

同一の環境で、WPF のプロジェクトを作成し、質問にある XAML を設定し、再現を行おうとしましたが、再現できませんでした。提示されている回避方法も実施していません。

例外が発生しないケースがあるといったようなことは、確認していないでしょうか？

理論上はツールチップにフェードイン・フェードアウトのアニメーションがかかっていないとエラーが発生しなくなるはずです。動画ではツールチップの表示にフェードインのアニメーションがかかっていないので、おそらくそれだと思います。OSの何かの設定で変わるのかもしれません。

 この設定のことですか？そうであれば、PopupAnimation が、Scroll や Slide の場合でも再現しますか？

ToolTip="Label"やToolTip="Left"のことです。Popup.PopupAnimationはどれでも、例えNoneであっても例外が発生します。OSの視覚効果の設定でツールチップのアニメーションが発生しないようにすることはできたのですが、相変わらずこちらの環境では例外が発生することがわかりました。例外の発生する・しないの差はどこか別のところにあるようです。
